# How to install cuttlefish in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, cuttlefish

I have tried the following command to install Cuttlefish

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noneed4anick/cuttlefish
```

But it did not work.Tell me if there is any other way to install cuttlefish

Comment: What is the error message say?

Comment: Is there an alternative to cuttlefish for taking actions or running scripts for various events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to stem from the fact that Cuttlefish is not yet compatible out of the box with Ubuntu 13.04. [This thread (See Post 10 specifically)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148382) appears to have found a workaround. Post 10 suggests that you should only have to download three dependencies:

[library for launchpad integration common data](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/liblaunchpad-integration-common) 
[library for launchpad integration](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1) 
[library for launchpad integration (gir files)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0)

Afterwards, just install Cuttlefish via: `sudo apt-get install cuttlefish`

Answer (score 1):

Visit this site

[Cuttlefish - Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~noneed4anick/+archive/cuttlefish/+packages)

or download

[cuttlefish_12.08_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~noneed4anick/+archive/cuttlefish/+files/cuttlefish_12.08_all.deb)