# task automation with Cuttlefish: get it working under 16.04 or suggest an alternative

Tags: 16.04, cuttlefish

To automate some simple tasks (e.g. disabling the track-pad when plugging a USB mouse, changing some config files when connecting to home or work WIFI, ...), I was using [Cuttlefish](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/automate-ubuntu-with-cuttlefish). The program works a bit similar to [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) on smartphones, in that you can perform certain actions based on various triggers. All triggers and actions can be chosen from a long list using a GUI. Call it programming for dummies, if you will, but it was a convenient way of performing some tasks without digging too deep into the internals of Linux.

Cuttlefish was working pretty well for me under Ubuntu 12.04, but these days it appears to be abandoned by the author. I managed to [install it for Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/03/install-cuttlefish-in-ubuntu-14-04-or-ubuntu-13-10/) using some PPA. This works more or less, but it keeps crashing several times a day, so it is effectively unusable.

Did anyone manage to get Cuttlefish working reliable under 14.04 or 16.04? Alternatively, is there a good replacement application, or do I need to start writing command line scripts again? I know that there are [alternative ways](https://askubuntu.com/a/58588/194613) to achieve some of the tasks I need, but this is too much black magic.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310559) answer?

Comment: Very interesting app, this Cuttlefish. What are the dependencies for this app ? If you have 12.04 , can you please run `apt-cache show cuttlefish` and let me know what dependencies are listed ? Also , are you interested only in getting this app working , or you could live with automating the usb mouse connecting/disconnecting  ?

Comment: Here is a .deb for 14.04 - https://launchpad.net/~noneed4anick/+archive/ubuntu/cuttlefish/+packages. I am not aware of alternatives.