# Is there a way to switch gpu's automatically when the battery is pluged in/off?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, battery

My notebook uses the so called Hybrid GPU (Intel and NVidia) and after installing the NVidia driver I am able to switch GPU's.

My question is whether it is possible to set it to use the Integrated graphics when the notebook is plugged off (in order to save battery) and the NVidia GPU when it is plugged in (So I could play stuff that requires the nvidia card).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not, actually. I do it on Nvidia X Server Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `cuttlefish` to automate activities when you plug/unplug AC power.

Switching between Nvidia and Intel graphics will still depend on using `bumblebee` or `prime-indicator`. I use `prime-indicator` but it requires the user to log out and log back in to switch.

Comment: Cuttlefish looks promising... Is it available on Ubuntu 16? If not, is it okay to install an older version?

Comment: I guess I haven't been keeping up on cuttlefish as it's no longer in the repository. This askubuntu question `http://askubuntu.com/questions/583838/` indicates it's not usable. Surprising for such a useful program. Sorry to point you in the wrong direction.